# Can't print on same line in VS Code notebook,`\b` and `\r` do not work

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I want to print on the same line in a VS Code notebook but it does not work.

`\b` also does not work well, it requires me to use two `\b` as a group to backspace.

I installed the Jupyter Notebook Extension. And I also tried in a Jupyter notebook, it's the same as in the VS Code notebook with the extension.

This is the code to reproduce the program:

```py
import time


def test_output():
        print('\b\b \b\b: OK', end='', flush=True)
        print(' -> Read: OK', end='', flush=True)
        print(' -> Json: OK', end='', flush=True)
        print(' -> Analysing...', end='', flush=True)


for i in range(15):
    print(f'\r{" " * 20}\r', end="", flush=True)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print(f"\rtest({i:02d}/15): Opening", end="", flush=True)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    test_output()
```

and this is the output:

```
test(14/15): OpeningK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing...
```

This is the code and output of `\b` not working:

```py
import time


def test_output():
        print('\b\b\b: OK', end='', flush=True)
        print(' -> Read: OK', end='', flush=True)
        print(' -> Json: OK', end='', flush=True)
        print(' -> Analysing...', end='', flush=True)


for i in range(15):
    print(f'\r{" " * 20}\r', end="", flush=True)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print(f"\rtest({i:02d}/15): Opening", end="", flush=True)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    test_output()
```

```
test(14/15): Opening OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing..: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing..: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing..: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing..: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing..: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing..: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing..: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing..: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing..: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing..: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing..: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing..: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing..: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing..: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing...
```

These problemr only occur in a notebook, whether in VS Code or Jupyter notebook. But if I run in the terminal, it will work well.

Comment: Traditional TTY-like terminals erase the previous character when they receive a backspace and move the cursor back to the beginning of line when they receive a carriage return; but notebooks do not.

Comment: seems like a [jupyter issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5681)

Comment: Looks like a known issue with jupyter. Also why is it necessary to use jupyter instead of py scripts? https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2892

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2892), the notebook only *emulates* a terminal; since `\b` is based on the cursor position and notebook do not emulate the cursor position, `\b` is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

What is supposed to happen exactly in your demo if it worked like you wanted? You don't specify.

#### Jupyter-based Option

Since `\b` doesn't work in Jupyter as others have said:
This gets close, I think (it's based on [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-can-i-repaint-the-output-in-one-cell/6000/5?u=fomightez)):

```py
import time

def test_output():
        print(f'{curr_prog}: Open: OK -> Read: OK  -> Json: OK  -> Analysing...', end=' ', flush=True)


for i in range(15):
    curr_prog=f"\rtest({i:02d}/15)"
    print(f"{curr_prog}: Opening                                            ", end="\r", flush=True)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    test_output()
    if i < 14:
        time.sleep(1.5)
```

---

Rich demo in Jupyter, adapted from [file_progress.py](https://github.com/Textualize/rich/blob/master/examples/file_progress.py):

```py
from time import sleep
from urllib.request import urlopen

from rich.progress import wrap_file

# Read a URL with urlopen
response = urlopen("https://www.textualize.io")
# Get the size from the headers
size = int(response.headers["Content-Length"])

# Wrap the response so that it update progress

with wrap_file(response, size) as file:
    for line in file:
        #print(line.decode("utf-8"), end="")
        sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: It shoule like this if it work well: `test(14/15): Open: OK -> Read: OK -> Json: OK -> Analysing...`

Comment: Tried to improve then. ..... By the way, [rich](https://github.com/Textualize/rich) does some nice progress pars that work in Jupyter. I added an example, too.